# Convert an unique line table into columns using the command line

Tags: awk, command-line, text-processing, data-analysis

My problem is convert the following text:

```
$ cat data.txt
M01
V100
V101
V102
V102
M02
V200
V201
V202
```

into this:

```
V100    M01
V101    M01
V102    M01
V102    M01
V200    M02
V201    M02
V202    M02
```

The lines start with V represent an index and the M are the values associates to them.

I'm trying to solve this in awk as follow:

```
$ awk '{if( $1 ~ /^M/ ){ m = $1; } else { print $m,$1; }}' data.txt
V100    V100
V101    V101
V102    V102
V102    V102
V200    V200
V201    V201
V202    V202
```

As you seen, doesn't work. The idea is store the M lines in a variable and later print it beside the V lines.  What is wrong? Is there another option from the command line?

thanks in advance!

Comment: `$m` is bash, in awk they are ordinary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^M/{m=$1;next} {print $0,m}' file
V100 M01
V101 M01
V102 M01
V102 M01
V200 M02
V201 M02
V202 M02
```